# Pivot Application Bug - Interfering with the GetGeopositionAsync() function

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, geolocation, winrt-xaml

I develop an application that uses Pivot pages.

I created the application with the default Pivot template, with background defined by a style "PageBackgroundStyle":

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="PivotApp.Views.MainPage"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        mc:Ignorable="d"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                        SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
                        Orientation="Portrait"
                        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Style="{StaticResource PageBackgroundStyle}">        

    <phone:Pivot x:Name="LocationPivot"
                 FontSize="{StaticResource LargeFontSize}"
                 LoadedPivotItem="Pivot_LoadedPivotItem">

        <phone:Pivot.Title>
            <TextBlock Text="Title"
                       FontSize="20"
                       Margin="0,0,0,10" />
        </phone:Pivot.Title>

        <phone:PivotItem  x:Name="one">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="one"
                           FontSize="50" />
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid />
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem  x:Name="two">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="two"
                           FontSize="50" />
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid />
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem  x:Name="three">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text"three"
                           FontSize="50" />
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid />
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The application calls (inside OnNavigatedTo) the GetGeopositionAsync() method. 
The code above works fine.

However, if I modify the code to show image background like this:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="PivotApp.Views.MainPage"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        mc:Ignorable="d"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                        SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
                        Orientation="Portrait"
                        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                    ImageSource="/PivotApp;component/Assets/PanoramaBackground.png" />
    </Grid.Background>

    <phone:Pivot x:Name="LocationPivot"
                 FontSize="{StaticResource LargeFontSize}"
                 LoadedPivotItem="Pivot_LoadedPivotItem">

        <phone:Pivot.Title>
            <TextBlock Text="Title"
                       FontSize="20"
                       Margin="0,0,0,10" />
        </phone:Pivot.Title>

        <phone:PivotItem  x:Name="one">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="one"
                           FontSize="50" />
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid />
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem  x:Name="two">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="two"
                           FontSize="50" />
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid />
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem  x:Name="three">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text"three"
                           FontSize="50" />
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid />
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

i.e. instead of background define by the style: PageBackGroundStyle (defined in App.xaml), I enter the code:

```
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                    ImageSource="/PivotApp;component/Assets/PanoramaBackground.png" />
    </Grid.Background>
```

the Image background is shown on the Pivot pages OK, however the GetGeopositionAsync() method is called and never returns.

Any idea if I am doing something wrong or there is a problem with the Pivot/Page?
Thx

Comment: These two things should be unrelated. Can you post the code of the OnNavigatedTo method?

Comment: The code in OnNavigatedTo is:
            BusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
            Location = await CoordinateConverter.GetLocation();
            if ( Location != null )
                {
                locationData.Latitude = Location.Latitude;
                locationData.Longtitude = Location.Longitude;
                }
            BusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
I tried the same code in "LoadedPivotItem" and it works fine there.

Comment: One more piece of information: The "GetGeopositionAsync()" is on a separate project (DLL) in the same solution.